# Why my Bash script won't even run if it is deployed in a web app?

Tags: bash, jakarta-ee, character-encoding

I created this simple script that does a backup, I wrote and tested it in Linux, then I copied it in my WebApp WEB-INF/scripts directory so that I could be run via Java Runtime.exec().

```
#!/bin/bash          

JACCISE_FOLDER="/var/jaccise"

rm $JACCISE_FOLDER/jaccisebackup.zip

zip -r jaccisefolder.zip $JACCISE_FOLDER 

mysqldump -ujacc -pxxx jacciseweb > jaccisewebdump.sql

zip jaccisebackup.zip   jaccisewebdump.sql    
zip jaccisebackup.zip   jaccisefolder.zip

rm jaccisewebdump.sql    
rm jaccisefolder.zip

cp  jaccisebackup.zip $JACCISE_FOLDER
```

But it doesn't. So I tried to copy it from WEB-INF/scripts to my user dir and run it to roubleshoot it. The result is that it comes out with: ": File o directory non esistente" (Means "Unknown file or directory" notice the colon at the beginning). I created another file from scratch, copied and pasted the whole script and it works. I may think that this is related to:

1. Text encoding
2. \n\r differences between windows (I use Eclipse on windows to edit everything) and Linux.

How do I solve this deploy problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the file is executable (chmod +x). Then you should check, if your web server allows the execution of external programs. This might be a security problem and it is likely that the web server prevents the execution. Check the logs of the web server. The encoding of the file can be changed with the dos2unix command. In order to debug your script you can add an "set -x" at the beginning, but I think the script does not start at all.

Comment: it was just an encoding problem. Using dos2unix solved it. Anyway how can I avoid this during deploy?

Comment: You will find the text file encoding in Window->Preferences and there General->Workspace.